# Android Project - RuntimeException , caused by Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I have got this class below and whenever I run this I get a runtime exception which I believe is caused by a Null Pointer Exception. I have included my Log Cat below.

Java File ;

```
public class Example extends Activity{
View v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);

    v.findViewById(R.id.eamplebutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Testing", "sd");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i=new Intent(Example.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
}
```

[LogCat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pdwbp3wx08j7et/logcat.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `v`, from `v.findViewById`

```
findViewById(R.id.eamplebutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Testing", "sd");
        }
    });
```

Activity's `findViewById` looks for the `id`, in the Activity's view hierarchy, the one build starting from what you pass as parameter to `setContentView`